# Spring MVC Interceptor Mapping Problems

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have this segment of XML:

```
<mvc:interceptors>
    <mvc:interceptor>
        <mvc:mapping path="/statics/**" />
        <bean class="com.company.website.servlet.StaticsHandlerInterceptor" />
    </mvc:interceptor>
    <mvc:interceptor>
        <mvc:mapping path="/data/**" />
        <bean class="com.company.website.servlet.AJAXHandlerInterceptor" />
    </mvc:interceptor>
    <mvc:interceptor>
        <mvc:mapping path="/**" />
        <bean class="com.company.website.servlet.PageHandlerInterceptor" />
    </mvc:interceptor>
</mvc:interceptors>
```

I have three different interceptors for a reason, though the `StaticsHandlerInterceptor` is just the `preHandle` method returning `true` (for all of my static content (js, css, etc)). The second one is for AJAX requests. The third one is for actual pages. What I see happening is the statics and the AJAX interceptors being called when they are supposed to be; however, with them, the page interceptor is always being called. I only want the page interceptor to be called for pages. How do I make that happen?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming you use a consistent naming scheme for your pages, use that - e.g. if your externally-visible page URLs end with `.html`, specify:

```
<mvc:mapping path="/**/*.html" />
```

It's not very RESTful to have "extensions" like that though - you might prefer to use a scheme like:

- GET of `/user/{id}` = returns User object for user {id}, JSON format
- POST to `/user/{id}` = updates User object from **JSON object**
- GET to `/user/page/{id}` = returns **HTML page** for user {id}
- etc etc

Then you can use a nice readable, semantic mapping like:

```
<mvc:mapping path="/**/page/**" />
```

which will work to any "depth" of URL structure.

**Edit:** OK so it seems that using the [mvc:interceptors](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-interceptors) style of bean declaration isn't going to give you the expressiveness you need to specify **exclusion** by pattern rather than inclusion.

From what I can make out in [this blog](http://www.scottmurphy.info/spring_framework_annotation_based_controller_interceptors), using the more-verbose `HandlerMapping` approach will allow you to *invert* the match logic - you can specify what *not* to match on to get what you need:

```xml
<bean id="nonStaticNonDataMapper" class="org.springplugins.web.IgnoreSelectedAnnotationHandlerMapping">
<property name="order">
    <value>0</value>
</property>
<property name="urls">
    <list>
        <value>/statics/**</value>
        <value>/data/**</value>
    </list>
</property>
<property name="interceptors">
    <list>
        <bean class="com.company.website.servlet.PageHandlerInterceptor" />
    </list>
</property>
```

<strike>(Apologies for the formatting of the above snippet, Markdown thinks the `/**` is a comment :-)</strike>

Comment: The problem is I have URLs like '~/index' and '~/preferences'. If the URL is '~/data/**', it's an AJAX request. If the URL is '~/statics/**', it's a request for static content. Otherwise, it will be a request for a page and I don't have extensions on my pages.

Answer (score 6):

mvc:interceptors now supports excluding a particular mapping.  Currently it's only available in Spring 3.2.0.M2.  You can find more about it at the JIRA item (that is now resolved): https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-6570

Comment: Note that differently from what is stated in the SPR-6570
    not <mvc:exclude-pattern path="/admin/**">
    but <mvc:exclude-mapping path="/admin/**"/>
should be used instead.