# Spring MVC: how can I re-load the logged-in user information from the database on each Thymeleaf page?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I'd like to show some information about the *logged-in user* in the header of my web site (so they should be available on each page that includes the header).

This information can change in the database and should be re-loaded when the user reload the page.

I wish there was a global object (e.g. `loggedInUser`), loaded from the database when a Thymeleaf page is returned from the server, so that I can access that object from Thymeleaf *without* having to pass it from each controller.

Is it possible to achieve something like that?

**** **UPDATE** ****

For example: I want to show notifications for the user in the header bar and these notifications can be added in the database server-side by various actions. When the user loads any page of the web site (that includes the header) notifications should be loaded server-side and shown in the header from Thymeleaf.

I would like to avoid to load the logged user in order to pass it to Thymeleaf on each controller serving a page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Load data for all or specific controllers with a [`@ControllerAdvice`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/ControllerAdvice.html) `@ModelAttribute` method

```
@ControllerAdvice(assignableTypes={FooController.class, BarController.class})
public class LoadGlobalData {

  @Autowired
  private MyUserDataService userDataService;

  @ModelAttribute("userData")
  MyUserData getUserData(){
        return userDataService.findByUser(...);
  }  
}
```

(Or you can use a Handler Interceptor for the above)

Use [method caching](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/cache.html) on your service

```
@Service
public class MyUserDataService {

  @Cacheable(value="userData", key="#userId")
  public MyUserData findByUser(long userId) {
    ...
  }

  @CacheEvict(value="userData", key="#userId")
  public void bust(long userId) {
    ...
  }
}
```

Use a database that support notifications, such as Oracle or [PostgreSQL](https://www.chrisstucchio.com/blog/2013/postgres_external_triggers.html) to bust your cache when data changes.

Comment: Thanks, your solution seems promising for my needs.. I don't understand what the class `LoadGlobalData` is?.. Is there a way to advise only some controllers to load my data (so I can limit the data loading only to controllers returning a thymeleaf page)?

Comment: @Andrea in latest v of spring you can config controlleradvice like u ask. Or you could write a handlerinterceptor.

Comment: Great!.. I used `@ControllerAdvice(assignableTypes = PagesController.class) ` where `PagesController` is my controller class with methods returning a Thymeleaf page. If you update the answer with your last suggestion will be perfect for my question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an interceptor to add stuff to the ModelAndView instance for every page served.

```java
public class AuthenticationUtil {
    private AuthenticationUtil() {} // private c'tor for utility class

    private static final AuthenticationTrustResolver authenticationTrustResolver = new AuthenticationTrustResolverImpl();

    /**
     * @return {@code true} if the user is authenticated non-anonymously
     */
    public static boolean isAuthenticated() {
        Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        return authentication != null &&
            authentication.isAuthenticated() &&
            !authenticationTrustResolver.isAnonymous(authentication);
    }
}
```

And the interceptor:

```
public class NotificationSettingInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {
    @Autowired
    private NotificationRepository notificationRepository;

    @Override
    public void postHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler, ModelAndView modelAndView) throws Exception {
        if (modelAndView == null) { // can be null for static resources etc.
            return;
        }

        if (AuthenticationUtil.isAuthenticated()) {
            Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
            modelAndView.addObject("notifications", notificationRepository.findNotificationsFor(authentication.getName()));
        }
    }
}
```

Create a bean from this Interceptor and register it, e.g. by overriding the `addInterceptors` method of your web `@Configuration` class (extending `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter`)

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    ...
    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        registry.addInterceptor(notificationSettingInterceptor());
    }
    ...
    @Bean
    public NotificationSettingInterceptor notificationSettingInterceptor() {
        return new NotificationSettingInterceptor();
    }
}
```

Or use the `<mvc:interceptors>` tag if you use xml namespace configuration:

```
<mvc:interceptors>
    <bean class="com.example.NotificationSettingInterceptor"/>
</mvc:interceptors>
```

Comment: Will be the interceptor's code executed on each request/response or only when the response is a Thymeleaf page?.. I have some controllers returning not a thymeleaf page but serving a JSON, I would like to avoid to load user's notifications also on these controllers because I don't need that.

Comment: You can scope an interceptor as described here to e.g. only handle /**/*.html:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8044277/spring-mvc-interceptor-mapping-problems

Comment: Thanks James.. I choose the @NeilMcGuigan answer because is simpler  and allow me to control where loading user informations by classes rather than by urls.

Answer (score 0):

You are thinking about session scope bean. Take a look at [Spring Docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-factory-scopes-session). You would create session bean after user logges and store necessary info there. Place where you inject such scoped bean can retrieve info about user. Or store more data into this cache.

But this makes you app state-full, which may be problem is your app is scaling horizontally. It wouldn't work if you are behind non-sticky load balancer, because there isn't guarantee that subsequent requests from your user will be routed to your same node where session instance is located.

EDIT: If you don't want to have state in your app, common solution is sending that data back and forth between client and server. But this approach consumes some bandwidth.

EDIT1: Another solution is to store that info in browser cookie. This will be send back and forth, between server and client.

Comment: what happen if the user informations changes into the database **after** the user is logged-in (and the session bean is already created)?.. are infos refreshed from db on new requests?

Comment: without your intervention, no. This is problem of state in your app. You generally want to avoid it. See my "edit" suggestion in answer.

Comment: what is the way to obtain what I asked without state?

Comment: see EDIT section of my answer

Comment: thanks @lkrnac, but maybe I poorly explained my problem.. see my update on the question, I added an example scenario hoping to give a better explaination... I don't know how can I achieve that using cookies :)