# Can I call a method after each @RequestMapping method is called?

Tags: java, spring

if we put the annotation @ModelAttribute before a method, it will be called before every request (before @RequestMapping)

Is there any similar way to call method **after** every request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to do this would be to define a [Spring Interceptor](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-handlermapping-interceptor) or more generally using AOP.

@ModelAttribute annoted methods serve a different purpose, their primary purpose is to set common model attributes, a side effect of which is that such methods need to be invoked before the actual @RequestMapped methods.

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5656124/proper-mvcinterceptor-configuration-in-spring