# HTTP Status 500 - Spring MVC unable to add interceptors

Tags: java, spring-mvc, interceptor

I'm getting an exception when I run this application on Tomcat 7 server. It runs perfectly fine when I don't add this piece of line on my dispatcherservlet.

```
<mvc:interceptors>
    <bean class="com.spring.maria.interceptor.PerformanceMonitorInterceptor" />
</mvc:interceptors>
```

but when I add it. I get this error.

[image]

I doubled check for spelling errors. There is none. I'm not sure whats causing the issue.

DispatcherServlet.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"     xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans      http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.0.xsd">

<mvc:annotation-driven enable-matrix-variables="true" />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.spring.maria" />
<mvc:resources location="/resources/" mapping="/resources/**" />

<mvc:interceptors>
    <bean class="com.spring.maria.interceptor.PerformanceMonitorInterceptor" />
</mvc:interceptors>

<!-- View Resolver -->
<bean
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>

<bean id="messageSource"
    class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="basename" value="messages" />
</bean>

<!-- File Uploading -->
<bean id="multipartResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
    <property name="maxUploadSize" value="10240000" />
</bean>

<!-- Java Object Conversion to XML/JSON -->
<bean
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver">
    <property name="defaultViews">
        <list>
            <ref bean="jsonView" />
            <ref bean="xmlView" />
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="jsonView"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.json.MappingJacksonJsonView">
    <property name="prettyPrint" value="true" />
</bean>

<bean id="xmlView"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.xml.MarshallingView">
    <constructor-arg>
        <bean class="org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller">
            <property name="classesToBeBound">
                <list>
                    <value>
                        com.spring.maria.domain.Product
                    </value>
                </list>
            </property>
        </bean>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

**Root Cause Error**

```
  org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping#0': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.MappedInterceptor#1': Could not resolve matching constructor (hint: specify index/type/name arguments for simple parameters to avoid type ambiguities)
```

[image]

Comment: view http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5656124/proper-mvcinterceptor-configuration-in-spring for correct answer (you have problem in xml configuration)

Answer (score 0):

Ahh, I forgot to include {extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter}. Thank You. It works now.