# I try to make the login code. but there is a error related to the interceptor

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, authentication, interceptor

I use the spring-mvc.

I wrote the code like this.
(I wrote the code in spring-mvc.xml; including mvc:view-controller, mvc:annotation-driven, etc.)

and there is a red-line under the 'interceptors' line.

Here is the code.

```
     <bean id="loginInterceptor" 
           class="kr.co.smartpayweb.login.controller.LoginInterceptor"></bean>

      <interceptors>
      <interceptor>
      <mapping path="/login/login.do"></mapping>
      <ref bean="loginInterceptor"/>
      </interceptor>
      </interceptors>
```

And the error message is below.

cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'interceptors'. 
One of '{"http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans":import...........}'

But I wrote this in the same file.

What do I need to do?

Comment: you can use `mvc:interceptor` I suppose. this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5656124/proper-mvcinterceptor-configuration-in-spring) may be helpful

Comment: thank you so much. I think I can do solve the problem! :)